# Find all positive integer pairs $(a, b)$ such that $(ab + a + b) \mid (a^2 + b^2 + 1)$.

Tags: number-theory, vieta-jumping

> Find all positive integer pairs $(a, b)$ such that $$(ab + a + b) \mid (a^2 + b^2 + 1)$$

Let $a^2 + b^2 + 1 = k(ab + a + b), k \in \mathbb N, k \ge 1$.

For $k = 1$, we have that $$a^2 + b^2 - ab - a - b + 1 = 0$$, where $(a, b) = (1, 1)$ satisfies the above condition.

For $k = 2$, we have that $$a^2 + b^2 - 2ab - 2a - 2b + 1 = 0$$, where $(a, b) = (n^2, (n + 1)^2)$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ satisfies the condition, since $$(a - b)^2 - 2(a + b) + 1 = [(n + 1)^2 - n^2]^2 - 2[(n + 1)^2 + n^2] + 1$$

$$ = (2n + 1)^2 - 2(2n^2 + 2n + 1) + 1 = (4n^2 + 4n + 1) - (4n^2 + 4n + 2) + 1 = 0$$

I don't know what to do next for the case of $k \ge 3$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is $k$ natural? Are $a,b$ natural?

Comment: How do you know that $(n^2, (n + 1)^2)$ is the only solution for $k = 2$? At least that's what it seems, though, like, you go directly into asking what to do when $k \ge 3$ :)

Comment: Observation: both $a$ and $b$ should be odd integers

Comment: This can be solved with “Vieta Jumping”, see for example https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1709711p11019108 or https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h610639p3630062 on AoPS.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference is HURWITZ 1907](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf)

Caution: this is about POSITIVE $x,y$ values. For $k=5,$ there is a solution at $-5,-3.$

The main thing is that the jumping step leads to inequalities for what Hurwitz called ground solutions. We have
$$ x^2 - kxy + y^2 -kx-ky +1=0 $$
To jump, the coefficient of $x$ is $-ky-k.$ The two $x$ solutions with $y$ fixed are $x$ and $x' = ky+k - x.$ A Grundlosung (it is an o umlaut) occurs when $x' \geq x$ and $y' \geq y.$ In turn, this says
$$ 2x \leq k(y+1)  \; \; , \; \; \; \; 2y \leq k(x+1)  $$
In the diagrams below, this is the region of the hyperbola in the first quadrant **between** the two lines. As you can see, there are actually no integer points on the arc between the two lines. For example, intersecting the hyperbola with $y = \frac{k}{2}(x+1)$ leads to
$$ x = \frac{6 k^2 \pm \sqrt{32} \sqrt{k^4 + k^2 - 2}}{4 - k^2} \; \; \; . \; \;  $$ 
As soon as $k \geq 3,$ we find $$  \sqrt{k^4 + k^2 - 2} < k^2 + \frac{1}{2}   $$
so that the numerator is positive for either $\pm,$ so that the final $x$ values are both negative. In turn, this means that there are **NO** integer points along the arc between the Hurwitz lines. There are, in fact, no fundamental solutions, therefore no (positive) integer solutions when $k \geq 3.$

[image]
[image]
[image]